# Client & Server messenger in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, client-server

*Server Code*

```
Private Function s_state(state As Integer)
    Select Case state
        Case 0
            s_state = "close"
        Case 1
            s_state = "open"
        Case 2
            s_state = "listening.."
        Case 6
            s_state = "connecting.."
        Case 7
            s_state = "connected.."
        Case 9
            s_state = "error"
        Case Else
            s_state = "close"
    End Select
End Function

Private Sub command3_click()
    socks.Close
    Text3.Text = s_state(socks.state)
End Sub

Private Sub command1_click()
    If socks.state = sckConnected Then
        socks.SendData Text1.Text
        Text3.Text = s_state(socks.state)
    Else
        MsgBox ("error...disconnect")
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load()
    socks.Close
    socks.Protocol = sckTCPProtocol
    socks.Listen
    Text3.Text = s_state(socks.state)
End Sub

Private Sub Command4_Click()
    If socks.state = sckClosed Then
        socks.Listen
    Else
        socks.Close
    End If
    Text3.Text = s_state(socks.state)
End Sub

Private Sub socks_ConnectionRequest(ByVal requestID As Long)
    If socks.state = sckListening Then
        socks.Acceptrequest id
        Text3.Text = "coonect to" & socks.RemoteHostIP
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub socks_DataArrival(ByVal bytesTotal As Long)
    Dim data As String
    socks.GetData data
    Text2.Text = data
    Text3.Text = s_state(socks.state)
End Sub
```

*Client Code*

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
    sockc.Protocol = sckTCPProtocol
    sockc.RemoteHost = Text4.Text
    sockc.RemotePort = Text5.Text
    Command3.Enabled = True
    Command4.Enabled = True
    Text3.Enabled = False
    Text4.Enabled = False
    Text5.Enabled = False
    Command5.Visible = True
    Command1.Visible = False
End Sub

Private Sub Command2_Click()
    If sockc.state = sckConnected Then
        sockc.SendData Text1.Text
        Text3.Text = s_state(sockc.state)
    Else
        MsgBox ("error...disconnect")
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Command3_Click()
    sockc.Close
    Text3.Text = s_state(sockc.state)
End Sub

Private Sub Command4_Click()
    If sockc.state = sckClose Then
        sockc.Connect
    Else
        sockc.Close
    End If
    Text3.Text = s_state(sockc.state)
End Sub

Private Sub Command5_Click()
    Command3.Enabled = False
    Command4.Enabled = False
    Text4.Enabled = True
    Text5.Enabled = True
    Command1.Visible = True
    Command5.Visible = False
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load()
    Command5.Visible = False
    Text3.Text = s_state(sockc.state)
End Sub

Private Function s_state(state As Integer)
    Select Case state
        Case 0
            s_state = "close"
        Case 1
            s_state = "open"
        Case 2
            s_state = "listening.."
        Case 6
            s_state = "connecting.."
        Case 7
            s_state = "connected.."
        Case 9
            s_state = "error"
        Case Else
            s_state = "close"
    End Select
End Function

Private Sub sockc_DataArrival(ByVal bytesTotal As Long)
    Dim data As String
    sockc.GetData data
    Text2.Text = data
    Text3.Text = s_state(sockc.state)
End Sub
```

Those codes are for client & server messenger but can't find the IP of server. Why those codes don't work, and why it can't connect to server?

Comment: Please, PLEASE get in the habit of giving your controls proper, descriptive names. It is very difficult to tell what anything is supposed to do here.

Comment: None of this code "finds" IP addresses. It appears that the user is responsible for typing the appropriate IP and port number into `Text4` and `Text5` respectively.

Comment: Yes, but when I get ip it does connect

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: I want get address and it connect .

Comment: Then send and receive message

Comment: There is no "easy" way to detect an IP address. At least one of the computers needs to know the address of the other before a connection can be made. If this is to be used over a local connection (like a small home network, or Intranet) you could research what is called [broadcasting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broadcasting_(networking)).

Comment: Can you debug this code and say what's the problem?